# Libreoffice converting docx to pdf in headless mode hangs

Tags: ubuntu, bash, libreoffice

```
Libreoffice: 6.3.1.2
cmd: --headless --convert-to pdf \"$basePath\" --outdir \"$dirPath\"
```

Can we set timeout to operation? or any other suggestions. So I want result that operation is not successful.